# Proper handling the user profile in .net core web API when Firebase authentication is used

Tags: firebase-authentication, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm going to build a .NET Core Web API (with a SQL Server database) as the backend application and react SPA as the frontend application.

For authentication, Firebase will be used.

In this project structure, where should I store additional user profile information? In Firebase or in my SQL Server database?

And should I use the builtin Identity tables to have a mapping between Firebase and my backend application (using `IdentityDbContext` or `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`) or create my own tables?

Comment: I think [`GetExternalLoginInfoAsync`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs#L224) is what you need. After setting up the Firebase OAuth provider